# Docker - Dockerfile publish to use selected publish profile

Tags: visual-studio, docker, kubernetes

First off, let me start by saying I am fairly new to docker and trying to understand the dockerfile setup.

We are currently trying to convert our existing WepApi services to support containerization and orchestration.  The plan is to use Docker with Kubernetes.  We currently utilize multiple publish profiles with then drive the WebConfig based on the selected publish profile.

Looking through the dockerfile, I see stuff such as:

```
RUN dotnet restore 
"Aeros.Services.Kubernetes/Aeros.Services.Kubernetes.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Aeros.Services.Kubernetes"
RUN dotnet build "Aeros.Services.Kubernetes.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Aeros.Services.Kubernetes.csproj" -c Release -o /app
```

Where the -c supplies the configuration.  Is there any way to get it to run this command based on the publishing profile the user has selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `ARG` statement in your Dockerfile.

```
ARG publishingProfile
RUN dotnet publish "Aeros.Services.Kubernetes.csproj" -c $publishingProfile -o /app
```

Use it like this from the command line:
`docker build --build-arg publishingProfile=Release`

Comment: Other option is to use an environment variable and pass it in during the build stage but in the case i think using the build arg is the correct way to go.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg

Comment: thanks everyone, I think that will get me going in the right direction.